# how to make app cannot quit without password?

Tags: android

I need to write an apps for tutorial class company. The company would like an apps which force users stay in the apps. Users cannot quit the apps with any method like press "home" button or back button. In the apps, there will be a button in apps called "quit". Users press this button and enter password to quit the apps.

I know how to disable and override the back button but cannot do well with home button and the  switching apps button.

Therefore, is there any good example which can do force user stay in the apps?

Comment: The home button is easy. That just launches the launcher, and you can write a custom launcher that pops up the password prompt. ;-)

Comment: You can't ovverride the home button in most commonly used versions of Android. It is a security issue.

Comment: What you're asking is, "How do I stop users from using their phone without my password?" Answer: You can't unless you root all their phones and run your script.  Would you try this on a Windows machine? i.e. Can't exit my program and use any other program unless you enter a password? -- the latter is rather possible, but neither request is appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young well, one can simply install another launcher to overcome the password prompt. I don't think there is a simple way. You might even need to build your own android.

Comment: Chris, May I have some example?

Comment: In fact, what I do is like the apps called "Kids Place". This apps is for parental control and force user only leave the "Kids Place" with required pin.

Comment: Android's Parental Lock feature is built into the OS itself. Like Onur said, you'd need to build your own android to achieve the same. By Parental Lock, I mean restricted user profiles.

Comment: The common way is to make a ROM for business users.

Comment: don't waste your time on doing this!!! this is not possible currently u need to update the existing OS for this!!!

Comment: I think you have an architectural design issue where the idea is easy but the implementation isn't possible. Why don't you take a different approach and just save where the user is in the process and then annoy the heck out of them until they complete?